# Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions when try to present viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, childviewcontroller

I'm getting `Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions` error when i try to present view controller which is previously added as child controller, how to resolve this?

> Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions

```
class VideoViewController: UIViewController {

}


class BigPlayerVC: UIViewController {
    let videoVC = VideoViewController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addChild(videoVC)
        view.addSubview(videoVC.view)
        videoVC.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    //  view.constrainViewEqual(videoReactController.playerView, top: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0, righta: 0)
        videoVC.didMove(toParent: self)
    }

    @objc func onBTNClick() {
        videoVC.willMove(toParent: nil)
        videoVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
        videoVC.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        videoVC.removeFromParent()
        self.present(videoVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the logs here and code on which vc presents which vc

Comment: @JoshuaFrancisRoman check now

Answer (score 2):

I have one temporary solution: Just move `present` method in DispatchBlock with delay
like below:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.1) {
    self.present(videoVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly the same problem as you. You should listen on `viewDidDisappeared` in `videoVC` and then present the view controller. Method `viewDidDisappeared` is called immediately, so you won't notice performance issues.

```
   @objc func onBTNClick() {
        videoVC.willMove(toParent: nil)
        videoVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
        videoVC.removeFromParent()
        videoVC.onViewDidDisappeared = {
             [unowned self, videoVC] in
             self.present(videoVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
             videoVC.onViewDidDisappeared = nil
        }
    }
```

```
final class YourViewController: UIViewController {
    var onViewDidDisappeared: (() -> Void)? = nil

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        onViewDidDisappeared?()
    }
```

[Edit] It's not only to remove unbalanced calls, but also remove UICollectionView unfocus issue that might appear on AppleTV